# Title: FLEMM_R2 Report Scheduling Issue - Works Locally, but Not Always

Tags: javascript, backend

I am facing an issue with the FLEMM_R2 report scheduling. The report is configured with the following config:

```
{
    "reportDetails": {
        "reportIcon": "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/faclonpics/organisation/faclon.png",
        "reportId": "FLEMM_R2",
        "subHeader1": "Consumption",
        "subHeader2": "jujuujujujujuju",
        "reportName": "FLEMM_R2",
        "title": "FLEMM_R2",
        "timezone": "Asia/Calcutta",
        "extension": "xlsx",
        "cycleTime": "00:00",
        "reportDuration": "currentMonth",
        "reportPeriodicity": "monthly",
        "devConfig": [
            {
                "devID": "INEM_DEMO_90",
                "sensorID": "VOLTS1"
            },
            {
                "devID": "INEM_DEMO_91",
                "sensorID": "VOLTS1"
            }
        ],
        "devConfigFormat": [
            {
                "devices": [
                    "INEM_DEMO_90",
                    "INEM_DEMO_91"
                ],
                "devicesName": [
                    "INEM_DEMO_90",
                    "INEM_DEMO_91"
                ],
                "sensor": "VOLTS1",
                "sensorName": "Voltage 1"
            }
        ],
        "clusters": [],
        "clusterUnit": {}
    },
    "extension": "xlsx",
    "repeat": "1",
    "invocationTime": "19:01",
    "invocationDays": [
        5
    ],
    "startTime": "18:58",
    "endTime": "18:58",
    "interval": "1",
    "selectedContacts": [
        {
            "_id": "62bbfdd1c64a2f5ce72d4fe9",
            "name": "Nikhil Srivastava",
            "mobiles": [],
            "emails": [
                "nikhil.faclon@gmail.com"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "scheduleName": "jujuujujujujuju"
}
```

The peculiar issue I am encountering is that the report is getting generated sometimes, but not always. When I generate it locally, it works fine, but when it runs on the server or the scheduled environment, it fails to generate consistently. I have verified the configuration settings and ensured that they are correct.